# RxJava - two observables

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I've got two observables - OnPeriodChanged and OnFilterChanged, and trying to figure out how to call a function for view adapter when one of them changes. I've tried .zip, but for some reason it does not get triggered:

```
Observable.zip(OnPeriodChanged, OnFilterChanged, (Date, Filter) -> HistoryViewModel.getScans(Date.first, Date.second, Filter)).subscribe(scans -> histAdapter.setScans(scans));
```

What I can use here to invoke the getter function and pass the results from it to setter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` will emit the items to the downstream only after both of your observables (`OnPeriodChanged`, `OnFilterChanged`) emitted. I think you are trying to 
call `HistoryViewModel.getScans` whenever any of the item changes, with latest values of `Date` and `Filter`. You could use `combineLatest` instead of `zip`

Try changing it to

```
    Observable.combineLatest(OnPeriodChanged, OnFilterChanged, (Date, Filter) -> HistoryViewModel.getScans(Date.first, Date.second, Filter))
            .subscribe(scans -> histAdapter.setScans(scans));
```

Comment: Yes, that’s what I had to do in the end; though I tried startWith and onNext on those two observables after setting up the observable, the combineLatest did the trick.